# Scrollable table in multitab form

Tags: html, css

I spent a lot of time searching for an answer to this, and can't seem to find anything to this specific question.
I have a form in which I declared 3 tabs, and in one of them, I want to display a list of elements in a table. I want this table to take all space available in height, an to be scrollable of the list is too long for the screen.
Here's my code so far:

```
    <div id="tab_accounts_form" style="display:block">
        <div class="tab_form">
            <table class="list_tab_form">
                @foreach (Company item in ViewBag.CompanyList)
                {
                    <tr class="row_tab_form">
                        <td class="col_rights_checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@item.ID"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col_rights_label">
                            @item.CodeAndName
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css:

```
.row_tab_form td
{
    height:19px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.list_tab_form
{
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.tab_form
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 2px ;
    position: relative;
    padding : 23px 0 0 0;
}

.tab_accounts_form
{
    height:100%;
}
```

WWith this code, and with a list longer than the available height, my list is not scrollable but displayed entireliy, so the page is scrollable. I also managed to set a fixed height to the list, so that it happends to be scrollable, but I want the height to be dynamic, so that it adapts to different screen sizes.

Thank you.

Edit: link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yo26bm0w/

Comment: Create a fiddle please

Comment: You can use `tbody` for that. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp

Comment: The tbody is generated by MVC, it is in the generated html code. This is a razor View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this, declaring my two blocks in a table of one row and two columns. It seems to be the only way to do this.